# Trouble getting regex to work with find

Tags: find, regular-expression

I'm having a lot of trouble getting `find` to work with regex flags. Im using `egrep` on its own to find a date pattern in a file, like this:

```
egrep '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
```

which will return dates formatted as CCYY-MM-DD just fine. I'm trying to use this same pattern with `find`. I have tried:

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"
find . -type f -regex "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"
```

Tried to backslash the curly brackets...

```
find . -type f -regextype egrep -regex "[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}"
```

All of these don't seem to return anything. I get no error messages, no output...
I have even tried to redirect the ouput to a file, but nothing...

It's hard to find good resources on using `find` with regex. 
If any one could help, I would greatly appreciate it. I'm not opposed to any of the types of regex `find` supports though I like `egrep` because of the `-o` flag for returning only the matches, NOT the entire line. But really I just need `find` to find all files in a directory that have a match of pattern above in the file name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example mixes single-quote and double quote.  And find wants a pattern which matches the whole filename, so you want to begin/end the pattern with '*'.

This will find all files that have the pattern you describe:

```
find yourpath -name "*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]*"
```

But if you want to use regextype, you need "posix-egrep", and note carefully that regex needs to match entire path,

```
find yourpath -regextype posix-egrep  -regex ".*[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

First example should be:

```
find yourpath -name "*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]*"
                               ^
```

Fourth bracket was wrong